# How to get the name of the file that is importing it in Python

Tags: python, file, import, module

I have 3 files, **main.py**, **module2.py** and **module3.py**.

Both module2.py and module3.py import main.py. I was wondering if there was a way to figure out which file was importing main.py.

To show what I am trying to achieve using code, this is what I would want to do with main.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(__name__)
else:
    print(name_of_the_file_that_is_importing_me) # module2 or module3
```

I have found some answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457308/how-do-i-find-the-name-of-the-file-that-is-the-importer-within-the-imported-fil), which is pretty outdated and doesn't exactly work the way I would like it to.

I hope the question makes sense and thanks to everyone in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1457354/8516516) using the `traceback` module, this code should work for your example.

main.py

```
import traceback

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(__name__)
else:
    stack = traceback.extract_stack()
    print(stack[0].filename)
```

Note that just grabbing stack 0 only works if you only have one layer of imports. If you have multiple layers of imports, then you need to work backwards up through the stack to pull out the immediate import.

If you have multiple layers of imports, this code should get the file making the immediate import.

```
import traceback

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(__name__)
else:
    stack = traceback.extract_stack()
    modules = [x for x in stack if 'importlib' not in x.filename]
    print(modules[-2].filename)
```

Note that the traceback module includes multiple layers of the importlib importing the module so this filters out those first and references the second to last module because the last module will be main.py so the second to last is the module making the immediate import.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much. But what do you mean by multiple layers of imports?

Comment: By multiple layers of imports, I mean if module3 imports module2 which imports main. My first solution would give you module3 in that case. My second solution would give you module2 in that case since module2 is what actual imports main.

Comment: I see what you mean. That is not a problem in my case. However, it would definitely be interesting to print all the layers of imports. I think it could be useful for debugging purposes in some cases. Anyway thanks a lot for the clarification!